# google-java-format: format whole project

Tags: java, checkstyle, google-java-format

I'm using google-java-format to format Java code according to Google Java Style. However, I only find documentation and examples showing how to format one file using the CLI.

Is there a built-in way to format an entire Java project directly using the CLI (without looping using a shell script or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick read of the google-java-format documentation,
it is intended to function one file at a time
or on a group of files,
each listed on the command line.

There appears to be plugins for intelliJ and Eclipse.

If you need to format every file in your project,
you will need to do one of the following:

1. Feed a list of every file.  This is fairly easy with a script; use xargs.
2. If you use IntelliJ, check the plugin options.  It likely has some kind of selection mechanism.
3. As above, the Eclipse plugin likely has some kind of selection mechanism, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if there were some kind of built-in mechanisms to achieve this. I'll try using a script. I've already tried to configure Eclipse to use the plugin but it seems it doesn't work properly. Maybe my Eclipse configuration is wrong somewhere. I'll dig into that and maybe raise an issue if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above suggests using `xargs`, so here's the command that I used:

```
find my_java_project/ -name "*.java" -type f -print | xargs java -jar google-java-format-1.18.1-all-deps.jar --replace
```

...where my current working directory contains my Java project (in the `my_java_project` folder) and the Google Java Format JAR.